# Skipping over the first worksheet in a loop in Openpyxl

Tags: python, loops, openpyxl

I'm looking to skip the first worksheet before searching for a specific number in the remaining sheets. My code so far:

```
wb = load_workbook("example.xlsx")


sheet1 = wb["Sheet1"]

sheet2 = wb["Sheet2"]

sheet3 = wb["Sheet3"]

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    #print(sheet)
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(2,sheet.max_row-1):
        numbers = row[9].value
        if numbers in [652850]:
            sheet3.append((cell.value for cell in row))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to `continue` on the first sheet. You could do that by checking the sheet title but can simply check if it is the first of the list in `wb.worksheets`.
see below;

```
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    #print(sheet)
    if sheet == wb.worksheets[0]:
        continue
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(2,sheet.max_row-1):
        numbers = row[9].value
        if numbers in [652850]:
            sheet3.append((cell.value for cell in row))
```